# WordPress WooCommerce mass huge XML products import with images

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, woocommerce

I am making a plugin to custom import a 120mb XML file with about 60k products to WooCommerce.

**How It works**
I have an Admin Page with some settings and fields etc.
-> Submit posts to self - `$_POST[...]` is detected as set and it attaches a class and starts the function.

1. XMLReader - gets the file and starts reading.
2. When 'Product' Element is found -> I'm making a `DOMDocument` and using `simplexml_import_dom`.
3. Checking for ids, names etc...
4. Mapping the seller ID with existing Category (XML FIle) -> not all categories are imported
5. Checking if the product exists: `wc_get_product_id_by_sku`
6. Getting the category ID by slugname: `get_term_by('slug', $categorySlug, 'product_cat');`
7. Adding the product with another function that uses the ready productArray: `WC_Product()`
8. uploading images with `media_sideload_image` also to get their ID's for WC_Product
9. Saving product `$newProductObj->save();`

XMLReader will skip a product if it exists or if the category is Excluded in maping XML file.
The XMLReader and script works fast.
It is getting slower due to database connections `wc_get_product_id_by_sku` and really by `media_sideload_image` and `$newProductObj->save();` WC_Product.

Biggest slow down is with images upload.

**Tried:**
I have set php.ini to get more memory etc.
I have used set_time_limit(0); in a while loop
I am unsetting unused vars.
Code without DB calls is fast reading, making objects, checking categories...

**Problems :)**
After a while server goes 503 or 500 CGI PHP something

**Question:**
How can I speed it up, make it more robust, so it will run... even for half a day, but run, without making the server stuck.

I hope you gus can help me out with it.

Comment: Try - https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/

Comment: Tried, it's useless for what we need.Problem stated is with php script looping, not getting a plugin.

Comment: function timeout is my main problem. Memory is fine. Script is fast.